# Sum Custom Field For Current User Only - Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

What I'm trying to do is query and sum a custom field in Wordpress for the current logged in user.

I have a website for my writing company that lets writers log in and claim work that they want to do. For each assignment, there is a field called "Word Count" where I input the word count for the article that needs to be done. To calculate how much each writer is owed for an assignment, I use the word count field (with the meta key "assignment_word_count" ) and multiply it by a flat rate that each writer is paid per word.

So far the closest script I've put together that does what I want it do is an SQL script. Unfortunately, it sums ALL of the word count fields instead of just the ones that belong to the current user. If I try to add anything to the code to limit it to the current user, the total drops to zero.

```
<?php
$now = current_time('mysql');
                $sql = "SELECT ";
                $sql .= "meta_value FROM $wpdb->posts AS posts, $wpdb->postmeta AS postmeta ";
                $sql .= "WHERE posts.ID = postmeta.post_id AND postmeta.meta_key =     'assignment_word_count' ";
                $sql .= "AND posts.post_status = 'paid' ";
                $sql .= "AND posts.post_date < '$now' ";
                $sql .= "AND postmeta.meta_value != '' ";
                $results = array(); $values = array();
                $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
                $totalpay = 0;
                if (!empty($results)){
                    foreach ($results as $result) {
                        $totalpay += $result->meta_value;
                    }
                }
                echo  'Total Paid: $' . $totalpay * money_format('0.0040=(#10.2n', $number);
?>
```

There's also another script I found that is supposed to do exactly what I'm looking for, but it tells me that the implode line is an invalid argument.

```
    <?php
        //get current user
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        // build query of ids by user
        $userPosts = get_posts(array('author' => $current_user->ID, 'post_type'=> 'assignments')); //change this

        // loop to create array of ids by user
        foreach ($userPosts as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post);
            $ids[] = get_the_ID();
        }
        $idList = implode(",", $ids); //tun this crap into a list

        $meta_key = 'assignment_word_count';//set this to your custom field meta key
        $totalpay = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
                                          SELECT meta_value
                                          FROM $wpdb->postmeta
                                          WHERE meta_key = %s
                                          AND post_id in (" . $idList . ")", $meta_key));
        echo 'Total pay: $ ' . array_sum( $totalpay);   ?>
```

Comment: Well formatted question and content and concise statement on what you're doing as well as expected result.  We just don't know what field contains the userID you're wanting to limit by.

Comment: Your query has no reference to Author. You need something like `$sql .= "AND author = '$current_user' ";` in there. As @xQbert said, we don't know your column or variable names so you will have to adapt that.

Comment: There is no reference to Author right now because I can't get it to work right. The user ID should be the current user. When I add the $sql .= "And author = '$current_user' " in there, it makes all of the other query results disappear and doesn't display any total at all, not even the "Total Paid: $" part of the echo.

Answer (score 0):

You should try first to fix your query with a hard coded user id, and then, in a second time, to work on how you pass the current user.

In the query, the right field name is post_author, not author.

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user    use this function and get currenet user id

and then

```
if(currentuserid=="meabox_user")
{

display the metaboxes

.........
}
```